# How to prove the map of rings $\mathcal{R} \to \mathcal{R'}$ is flat?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-numbers, witt-vectors

We fix a finite extension $K$ of $p$-adic field $\mathbb{Q}_p$ with ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ and residue field $\kappa$. Consider the ring of witt vectors $W(\kappa)$ over the residue field $\kappa$ of characteristic $p>0$. Define the ring  of power series $\mathcal{R}:=W(\kappa)[[u]]$ and its localisation at the prime ideal $(p)$ by $\mathcal{R}_{(p)}$. Denote the completion of $\mathcal{R}_{(p)}$ by $\mathcal{R'}:=\widehat{\mathcal{R}_{(p)}}$.

**My questions:**

> $(1)$ How to prove the map of rings $\mathcal{R} \to \mathcal{R'}$ is flat ?

> $(2)$ How to prove the map of rings $\mathcal{R}_{(p)} \to \mathcal{R'}$ is faithfully flat ?

Help me at least with algorithm behind the proof. For example, I am trying the first question:

To show the map of rings $\mathcal{R} \to \mathcal{R'}$ being flat, we have to show that $\mathcal{R'}$ is flat $\mathcal{R}$-module. That is, we have to show the $\text{tensor product functor}$ $- \otimes_{\mathcal{R}} \mathcal{R'} $ or $\mathcal{R'} \otimes_{\mathcal{R}}-$ is a exact functor.
Consider the short exact sequence $$  0 \to \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{B} \to \mathcal{C} \to 0$$ of $\mathcal{R}$-modules $\mathcal{A},~ \mathcal{B},~  \mathcal{C} $. We have to show that the following sequence $$  0 \to \mathcal{A}\otimes_{\mathcal{R}} \mathcal{R'}  \to \mathcal{B}\otimes_{\mathcal{R}} \mathcal{R'} \to \mathcal{C}\otimes_{\mathcal{R}} \mathcal{R'} \to 0$$ is also short exact sequence. That is, we have to show that the map $\mathcal{A}\otimes_{\mathcal{R}} \mathcal{R'}  \to \mathcal{B}\otimes_{\mathcal{R}} \mathcal{R'}$ is injective.

How to define this map here ?

Help please.

Comment: For any noetherian ring $R$ and prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$, the localization map $R\rightarrow R_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is flat; if $R$ is local,  the completion map $R\rightarrow \hat{R}$ is faithfully flat.

Comment: @abx, How to prove the statements, which you said? I need to know the proofs. Or at least attach the reference please

Comment: This is completely standard, you'll find this in any commutative algebra book (Atiyah-MacDonald, Matsumura, Bourbaki...). Please use [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com) for basic questions.

Comment: @abx, Ok, can you please comment about the $method \ 2$ approach above ?

Comment: No. I don't think it makes sense to use the special properties of Dedekind rings to prove a completely general (and well-known) result.

Comment: @abx, I have still a problem. How to see the map $\mathcal{R} \to \mathcal{R} \left[ \frac{1}{u} \right]$ is flat ?, where $\mathcal{R}=W(\kappa)[[u]]$. How to show this map is flat ?  Is $\mathcal{R} \to \text{Frac}(\mathcal{R})$ a flat map ?

Comment: Yes, it is. As I already said, any localization map $R\rightarrow S^{-1}R$ is flat.

Comment: @abx, I understand the localisation map $\mathcal{R} \to S^{-1} \mathcal{R}$ is flat over Noetherian ring. But the map $\mathcal{R} \to \mathcal{R} \left[\frac{1}{u} \right]$ is different from localisation map. Can you show the work to prove the later map is flat ? Please also see my edited question and diagram.

Comment: It **is** a localization map, with $S=\{u^n\}$.

Comment: @abx, Thank you very much